# Finding path of a resource within eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an eclipse plugin in which I want to run some scripts depending on the menu options selected, these scripts are part of the jar itself. I am able to get the path of these scripts when I run the plugin project as an eclipse application from eclipse itself. But when the project is exported as a plugin (jar), placed in 'eclipse/features' and used in eclipse there are issues in resolving the paths for these scripts within the jar.
I tried the following different ways that I could find in SO but the issue unsolved. 
Basically I want to know how to get the path of the plugin programatically, so that from the path of the plugin I can construct the actual path of the scripts.

Id of the plugin : MyPlugin

Trial 1:

```
String scriptLocation = FileLocator.toFileURL(Platform.getBundle("MyPlugin").getEntry("src/"+scriptName)).getPath();
```

Trial 2:

```
URL url = new URL("platform:/features/ade/src/"+scriptRelativePath);

String scriptLocation = FileLocator.toFileURL(url).getPath();
// This gave a runtime error, :features is not applicable to protocol 'platform'
```

Trial 3:

```
URL url = new URL("platform:/plugin/ade/src/"+scriptRelativePath);

String  scriptLocation = FileLocator.toFileURL(url).getPath();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("relative path"), null);

url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```

The 'relative path' is the path relative to the plugin root.

`FileLocator.toFileURL` may unpack the resource in to a temporary location.